# navCtrl.pop and navCtrl.removeView removing wrong pages on iphone

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

We are using Ionic 3.9.2 and are having a strange intermittent error on iPhones.

On a specific page, when calling `this.navCtrl.pop()` (triggered by the user clicking the close button), it's removing the pages below it (including the root page) but not the specific page itself.
When the user clicks the close again, these errors are triggered:

> You can't remove all the pages in the navigation stack. nav.pop() is probably called too many times

and

> Unhandled Promise rejection:
>   navigation stack needs at least one root page

I tried replacing the pop() method with `this.navCtrl.removeView(this.viewCtrl, { animate: false });` but still have the same problem.

Has anyone else come across such a bug?

Comment: Can you add some codes?

Comment: And could you elaborate what close button you are talking about?

Comment: Could you provide us with a Minimum Complete Verifiable Product?

Answer (score 0):

Is this page pushed? Or setted like root?
To use .pop(), the page must be pushed

Maybe?

import { App } from 'ionic-angular/components/app/app';

```
/* define in constructor */
constructor(public platform: Platform, app: App){
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
            app.navPop();
        });
    })       
}
```

Comment: This page is pushed.

Comment: @RafaelBorochov answer edited? Catch the backbutton, hardware